# Зачем мне маршрутизатор? Почему в домашней сети нельзя обойтись модемом?

Tags: сеть, маршрутизация, маршрутизатор

Готовлюсь к экзамену по сетям.
Имеется вот такой слайд:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, а зачем мне вообще маршрутизатор в квартире?
Ведь так или иначе все мои запросы идут через сервер провайдера.
Какую роль выполняет маршрутизатор?
Ведь у него нет выбора куда посылать пакет, он же подключён только к серверу провайдера? Или я что-то не понимаю!

Comment: Если только посылать пакеты наружу и ничего оттуда не принимать, то действительно не нужен.

Comment: *"он же подключён только к серверу провайдера?"* – у вас же на картинке это не так. Если же у вас в квартире только один компьютер и нет устройств с вайфаем, то да, он вам действительно без надобности.

Comment: Ну да, точнее, не он (роутер), а модем подключён к провайдеру. Но обычно это одно устройство, поэтому так и говорю. Даже если много компов в доме, разве не достаточно было бы одного лишь коммутатора (switch) ?

Comment: По поводу первого комментария, так выходит что роутер не может проложить маршрут на swith или на модем? Роутер может проложить маршрут только на другой роутер, поэтому чтобы принять пакет он нужен по любому. Так?

Comment: Модем и роутер это разные устройства. Совмещение бывает, но нечасто. Коммутатора теоретически могло бы быть достаточно, но тогда провайдеру может быть не вполне понятно, с каким лицевым счётом ассоциировать каждое ваше устройство. Но тут уже начинаются вопросы о способе организации доступа в интернет от конкретного провайдера: напрямую ли через шлюзы по умолчанию, или нужен тоннель с логином и паролем...

Comment: _Роутер может проложить маршрут только на другой роутер, поэтому чтобы принять пакет он нужен по любому. Так?_ - Не так. Рутер (в контексте моего комментария) нужен чтобы отдать пришедший пакет тому, кто его запрашивал - инстаграмку айфону, мультик телевизору, апдейт на винду ноутбуку.

Comment: Модем для провайдера - это одно устройство и провайдер на него выдаст в общем случае только один ip-адрес. И если у вас более одного устройства пользуются этим модемом то кто то должен раздать вашим устройствам адреса и при передаче преобразовать из в один адрес. выданный провайдером. Вот этим и занимается маршрутизатор, потому что все современные домашние маршрутизаторы имеют функцию NAT